# How to combine different images to make single image of Panorma in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, panorama-control

I want to build a app which takes 360 degree panorama picture in iPhone new and older version. For this I want to take multiple images when iPhone rotates and when it come back to its position then all the images should be merged in to a single horizontal image to make it as panorama. Here two things which I require.

First merge multiple images

Second Image should be automatically captured when device rotates or move in right direction.

Please provide any suggestion to achieve this.

What I plan for it is I start taking Pics when the accelerometer changes and pause it when accelerometer stop. Also when the accelerometer come to its older position then stop and merge all images in a single image. Is it possible??

Thanks

Comment: This is very vague. What have you tried?

Comment: I have the idea to show the image in panoramic view.

Comment: You're talking about a fairly large feature, we're here to answer specific questions, not "how do I build this app?"

Comment: I am not asking about app building. I am asking about an API for combining multiple images

Answer (score 2):

This is a very advanced topic so you should be familiar with some image editing algorithms. To merge the pictures I would use CoreGraphics. You will have to use Apples camera capture api to take photos and save the rotation at the same time by using the inbuilt gyroscope. I guess you are familiar with these topics since you want to start such a huge project. There are some good image stitching algorithms that you might want to implement. You can find a good introduction here: http://cs.bath.ac.uk/brown/papers/ijcv2007.pdf.

---

I think I misunderstood you! So what you are trying to do is

1. Take a picture
2. Wait for the accelerometer or gyroscope delegate to fire up
3. Take another picture
4. Merge the new picture with the old one
5. Go back to 2.

Most points should be pretty straightforward but 4 could be difficult. You could use CoreGraphics to do the image editing. There is a good basic introduction here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93563/Introduction-to-iOS-Graphics-APIs-Part-1. But i you really want good outpur and not only save the new picture in the old one with an offset you will really have to look at image stitching algorithms. A good starting point for that would be the link in my previous post.

To atol the panorama once you come back to your starting point you will have to add all the accelerometer and gyroscope changes together and check if they are nearly one.

EDIT:

I think I misunderstood you! So what you are trying to do is

Take a picture
Wait for the accelerometer or gyroscope delegate to fire up
Take another picture
Merge the new picture with the old one
Go back to 2.
Most points should be pretty straightforward but 4 could be difficult. You could use CoreGraphics to do the image editing. There is a good basic introduction here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93563/Introduction-to-iOS-Graphics-APIs-Part-1. But i you really want good outpur and not only save the new picture in the old one with an offset you will really have to look at image stitching algorithms. A good starting point for that would be the link in my previous post.

To atol the panorama once you come back to your starting point you will have to add all the accelerometer and gyroscope changes together and check if they are nearly one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I plan for it is I start taking Pics when the accelerometer changes and pause it when accelerometer stop. Also when the accelerometer come to its older position then stop and merge all images in a single image. Is it possible??